# Requirejs in node executing call twice for no reason?

Tags: node.js, requirejs, synchronization

Trying to get my head around using requirejs in node, when I run a sync call as described in the RequireJS in Node manual with the following...

```
//Retrieves the module value for 'a' synchronously
var a = requirejs('a') )
```

However when I've tried this approach it executes the request twice?

part0_start.js...

```
var requirejs = require('requirejs');
requirejs.config({
    nodeRequire : require 
});
var part1_setup = requirejs( 'part1_setup' ) 
console.log( 'part1_setup complete')
```

part1_setup.js...

```
requirejs([], function() {
    console.log( 'setup');
})
```

this should output...

```
setup
part1_setup complete
```

but instead it outputs...

```
setup
setup
part1_setup complete
```

Can anyone enlighten me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to replace your `requirejs` call in your `part1_setup.js` with `define`.

When you use RequireJS in node, there's a peculiarity: if RequireJS fails to load a module by itself, it will try to get Node's `require` to load the module. Here's what happens with your code:

1. `var part1_setup = requirejs( 'part1_setup' )` tells RequireJS to load your `part1_setup1` module. Note here you are using a synchronous form of the `require` call (well, it's name is `requirejs` but it is really RequireJS' `require` call). Whereas in a browser such call is not *really* synchronous (and your specific call would fail), in Node it is truly synchronous.
2. RequireJS loads your module and executes it. Because you do not have an anonymous `define` in it (a `define` that does not specify a module name), the module loading fails. You need an anonymous `define` for RequireJS to determine what factory function it should run so that the module is defined. However, the code in the file *is* executed so you are telling RequireJS "when the dependencies `[]` have loaded, then execute my callback". There is nothing to load. RequireJS executes the callback that prints `setup`.
3. **This is special to running RequireJS in Node:** Because the module loading failed, RequireJS then calls Node's `require` function with your module name. Node looks for the module and loads it. So Node executes the code in the file a second time, and again `requirejs([],...` is executed, which means the callback that prints `setup` runs again.

You should always have a `define` in your module files rather than a `require` (or `requirejs`) call.