# using requirejs with node

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs

I'm currently working on a server side Node project.  Although node has it's own module loader using CommonJS I'm evaluating whether to use RequireJS with it.  Whilst there are advantages to using RequireJS with Node if the application that has some client side aspects to it, I can't find any benefits for a project which is entirely server side.

Is it commonly thought that for a 100% server side Node project, there are no real advantages to incorporating RequireJS?

Comment: What's the question, I agree using requirejs has no benefit for nodejs. As it already has pretty good java like loading abilities, `require('./file')` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There exist reasons to use RequireJS server-side but they are few. Unless you can state a reason, like:

> I *must* use RequireJS because X

where "X" is a reason which justifies the use of RequireJS, then you should not do it.

Note that just wanting to write modules in the AMD format is not reason enough as there exist loaders (like [node-amdl-loader](https://github.com/ajaxorg/node-amd-loader)) which allow loading AMD modules in Node. I actually use this when I want to test code which does not depend on a browser. I write the modules in AMD format and specify that if used in Node, an AMD loader like node-amd-loader should be used. This way the library works both in Node and in the browser but I test it in Node.

One reason to use RequireJS server-side is for instance, if you need to run code that needs a DOM implementation. If you use something like [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) to provide the DOM and the code you want to load is a series of AMD modules, then using RequireJS to load the code into the DOM environment created by jsdom makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I guess the main reason is to allow me to be consistent in my dev stack.  Typically my work isn't exclusively server side.  

If there was no down side in terms of performance, or the potential to overcomplicate and possibly cause package compatibility issues I would still use it.

Would you say using requirejs adds much of an overhead in terms of load/processing time given it's being loaded alongside an existing module loader.  Or does it make up for this by being faster than CommonJS?

Comment: In may cases the very desirable goal of consistency can be achieved with using an AMD loader like node-amd-loader, and skipping RequireJS entirely. RequireJS is not bad by any means but it is trying to solve problems that are peculiar to the browser environment. Running it in Node without having a substantial reason that *necessitate* means dealing with the additional peculiarities of RequireJS. For instance, in [your question there](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31039014/1906307) your code would work just as well with CommonJS and not cause mysterious double-loading issues.

Answer (score 0):

I've never found a good reason to use `RequireJS` in node. However, [RequireJS can be run on node](http://requirejs.org/docs/node.html), and the documentation has a brief explanation of why you might want to run `RequireJS` on a Node server:

> By using RequireJS on the server, you can use one format for all your
>   modules, whether they are running server side or in the browser. That
>   way you can preserve the speed benefits and easy debugging you get
>   with RequireJS in the browser, and not have to worry about extra
>   translation costs for moving between two formats.

Most of that is only useful in a project that also has a client element. If it were me, I'd stick with [Node's internal module loader](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders).